# Using R and with the Terminal

Tags: r, batch-file, terminal

I have combed the internet looking for a tutorial on how to use R through the terminal and I can't find anything that exactly fits what I'm looking for. I have a group of R scripts. They need to be run in a specific order. Each produces a set of .csv files to be used as inputs for the next script that will be executed.

I have used `R CMD BATCH filename.R` and it makes an output file called `filename.Rout`

But then when I try to use `cat filename.Rout`, I get an error `Fatal error: cannot open file 'filename.R': No such file or directory`

Also I'm not sure where my output (.csv files) should be written to. In my R script, there are some `write.csv` lines pointing the new datasets to be written to a specific directory but when I run `R CMD BATCH filename.R` in the Terminal, I don't see the files where they should be. I see a `filename.Rout` in another directory but I can't open it.

Comment: Look at Rscript (and maybe littler) and the large number of questions here about them.

Comment: Also ensure that the user which you're running the process with has the appropriate permissions to write to that directory.

Comment: sounds like `cat` is working fine... the "fatal error" is from R, not from trying to open `filename.Rout`.  Are you in the right working directory in terminal when you execute `R CMD BATCH filename.R`?  sounds like R can't find it.

Comment: Need to see the content of `filename.R`.